# Labeling using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make the label C to not overlap with a line. What should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\PHI{1.61803}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,z=4.5,scale=1.5]
\coordinate (A) at (\PHI, 1 , 0);
\draw (\PHI, 1 , 0) node[above right] {$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (\PHI, - 1 , 0);
\draw (\PHI, - 1 , 0) node[below right] {$D$};
\coordinate (C) at ( - \PHI , - 1 , 0);
\coordinate (D) at ( - \PHI , 1 , 0);
\coordinate (E) at ( - 1, 0 , \PHI);
\coordinate (F) at (1 , 0 , \PHI);
\coordinate (G) at ( - 1 , 0 , - \PHI);
\coordinate (H) at (1 , 0 , - \PHI);
\draw (1 , 0 , - \PHI) node[above = 0.7mm] {$C$};
\coordinate (I) at (0 , \PHI , 1);
\draw (0 , \PHI , 1) node[above] {$D$};
\coordinate (J) at (0 , \PHI , - 1);
\coordinate (K) at (0 , - \PHI , - 1);
\coordinate (L) at (0 , - \PHI , 1);
\draw[dashed] (A)--(F)--(B);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(L)--(F);
\draw[dashed] (E)--(F)--(L)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(E)--(L)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(E)--(D);
\draw[dashed] (E)--(I)--(F);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(L)--(K);
\draw (I)--(J)--(A)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (I)--(J)--(D)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A)--(H)--(B);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(K)--(H)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (G)--(K)--(H);
\draw[dashed] (C)--(G)--(K)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(G)--(D);
\draw[dashed] (G)--(D)--(J)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (G)--(J)--(H);
\draw[dashed] (A)--(H)--(J)--cycle;
\draw (A)--(I)--(D)--(C)--(K)--(B)--cycle;
\draw (I)--(J);
\draw (D)--(J);
\draw (G)--(J);
\draw (H)--(J);
\draw (A)--(J);
\draw (D)--(G);
\draw (C)--(G);
\draw (K)--(G);
\draw (H)--(G);
\draw[thick] (G)--(H);
\draw (A)--(H);
\draw (B)--(H);
\draw (K)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw (1 , 0 , - \PHI) node[above = 2mm] {$C$};`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I comment `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`. Anyone uncommenting this may need to know that, [as pointed out by muzimuzhi Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532371/labeling-using-tikz/532407?noredirect=1#comment1346218_532407), you need  then to compile with e.g. `latex` and run `dvipdfmx` or `xdvipdfmx`.

Anyway, as for the main question, all you need to do is to be a bit more generous, instead of `above = 0.7mm` use e.g. `above = 2mm` to get

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\PHI{1.61803}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,z=4.5,scale=1.5]
\coordinate (A) at (\PHI, 1 , 0);
\draw (\PHI, 1 , 0) node[above right] {$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (\PHI, - 1 , 0);
\draw (\PHI, - 1 , 0) node[below right] {$D$};
\coordinate (C) at ( - \PHI , - 1 , 0);
\coordinate (D) at ( - \PHI , 1 , 0);
\coordinate (E) at ( - 1, 0 , \PHI);
\coordinate (F) at (1 , 0 , \PHI);
\coordinate (G) at ( - 1 , 0 , - \PHI);
\coordinate (H) at (1 , 0 , - \PHI);
\draw (1 , 0 , - \PHI) node[above = 2mm] {$C$};
\coordinate (I) at (0 , \PHI , 1);
\draw (0 , \PHI , 1) node[above] {$D$};
\coordinate (J) at (0 , \PHI , - 1);
\coordinate (K) at (0 , - \PHI , - 1);
\coordinate (L) at (0 , - \PHI , 1);
\draw[dashed] (A)--(F)--(B);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(L)--(F);
\draw[dashed] (E)--(F)--(L)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(E)--(L)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(E)--(D);
\draw[dashed] (E)--(I)--(F);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(L)--(K);
\draw (I)--(J)--(A)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (I)--(J)--(D)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A)--(H)--(B);
\draw[dashed] (B)--(K)--(H)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (G)--(K)--(H);
\draw[dashed] (C)--(G)--(K)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (C)--(G)--(D);
\draw[dashed] (G)--(D)--(J)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (G)--(J)--(H);
\draw[dashed] (A)--(H)--(J)--cycle;
\draw (A)--(I)--(D)--(C)--(K)--(B)--cycle;
\draw (I)--(J);
\draw (D)--(J);
\draw (G)--(J);
\draw (H)--(J);
\draw (A)--(J);
\draw (D)--(G);
\draw (C)--(G);
\draw (K)--(G);
\draw (H)--(G);
\draw[thick] (G)--(H);
\draw (A)--(H);
\draw (B)--(H);
\draw (K)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Package option `dvipdfmx` is for dvi mode + (x)dvipdfmx backend. For example, xelatex or latex + (x)dvipdfmx.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks a lot!